# In mailto: body i wanted to enter some text with enter characters

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I wanted to create a mailto link with preset body content having some text displayed on new lines. 
Its similar to the below image.

Currently i am creating it using below command but body text comes in a single line with br tags

```
<a href="mailto:sales@xyz.com&subject=Want to subscribe (Android)&body=Name: <br>Business: <br>Address: <br>Contact No.:">
```

Can you please help me achieve this?

[image: body with enter characters]

Answer (score 5):

Try this piece of code

```
body=Hello,%0D%0AI want your help!
```